# Modifying a discrete probability distribution according to set of weights

Tags: probability, terminology, transformation

Given a discrete probability distribution (e.g., ${P_1=0.85,P_2=0.05,P_3=0.05,P_4=0.05}$), I would like to transform it according to some set of "weights" (say, ${w_1=2,w_2=0.5,w_3=1,w_4=0.5}$), which in this case would increase $P_1$ by some amount, decrease $P_2,P_4$ by some amount, and leave $P_3$ the same. Simply multiplying $p_i w_i$ won't do. I was thinking along the lines of casting both as a matrix, but the question would then be, what properties would W need to satisfy such that $\Sigma p_i$ is always 1?

Comment: Won't _any_ transformation do?  If $Y = g(X)$ where $g$ is any (bounded) function, then for any $\beta$, $$P\{Y = \beta\} = \sum_{\alpha ~ \colon ~\beta = g(\alpha)} P\{X = \alpha\}.$$ Where do you think the probability mass will disappear to (or appear from) to make the sum of probabilities in the new distribution less than (or more than) $1$?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: Given a discrete probability distribution (e.g., $\{ P_1 = 0.85, P_2 = 0.05, P_3 = 0.05, P_4 = 0.05 \}$, I would like to transform it according to some set of "weights" (say, $\{ w_1 = 2, w_2 = 0.5, w_3 = 1, w_4 = 0.5 \}$), which in this case would increase $P_1$ by some amount, decrease $P_2,P_4$ by some amount, and leave $P_3$ the same.  Simply multiplying $p_i w_i$ won't do.  I was thinking along the lines of casting both as a matrix, but the question would then be, what properties would W need to satisfy such that $\Sigma p_i$ is always 1?

Comment: What you seemed to be asking and what you seem to want are very different things.  Why not incorporate your above response into a revised question so people can understand what it is that you are asking, and respond appropriately?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate:  Done.  I'll leave my comment, unless Stack Exchange protocol says to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what exactly the OP wants.

Let us call a $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ a *stochastic vector* if $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ for 
$1 \leq i \leq n$,  and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$.  Let us call a stochastic
vector  a *proper* stochastic vector if each $x_i > 0$.  We are given a
proper stochastic vector $\mathbf P = (P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_n)$. Each
real vector $\mathbf w = (w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_n)$ defines 
a transformation 
$$w: \mathbf P \to w(\mathbf P) = (w_1P_1, w_2P_2, \cdots, w_nP_n).$$

- Given an arbitrary  stochastic vector $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, is there a $\mathbf w$ such that $w(\mathbf P) = \mathbf x$?

  > Obviously yes.  We have $w_i = x_i/P_i$
  >   for $1 \leq i \leq n$.  Note that 
  >   the $w_i$ are all nonnegative real numbers.
- Characterize the set of all $\mathbf w$ such that $w(\mathbf P)$ is a 
  stochastic vector.

  > This is a lot harder.  Obviously, it is necessary that
  >   each $w_i$ satisfies $0 \leq w_i \leq P_i^{-1}$, but as Ross Millikan says,
  >   there is not much else that can be said except that the $w_i$ must be such 
  >   that $\sum w_iP_i = 1$, that is, $w(\mathbf P)$ must be a stochastic
  >   vector.  We could dress it up probabilistically and say that 
  >   the $\mathbf w$ are the set of all possible ranges that a nonnegative 
  >   discrete random variable $X$ with $E[X] = 1$ can have, where the 
  >   probability mass function of $X$ is constrained to be
  >   $$p_X(w_i) = P\{X = w_i\} = P_i, ~ 1 \leq i \leq n$$
  >   but where is the fun in that?

Most important, the transformation that the OP seeks has nothing to do
with probability theory per se as I mistakenly thought in my initial 
comment on the question: we are *not* transforming one random variable 
into another and deriving the probability mass function of the image 
from the probability mass function of the source.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rescale by the sum of the weights $W$.  It sounds like you want $P_1:P_2:P_3P_4=1.7:0.025:0.05:0.025$, but you are correct the sum must be $1$.  So $W=1.7+0.025+0.05+0.025=1.8$ and the new values are $P_1=1.7/1.8, P_2=0.025/1.8$, etc.

Comment: This makes sense, but what if I would like to avoid rescaling.  For a probability distribution $P = \{ p_i \}$, I know that every $p_i$ must satisfy $(0 \leq p_i \leq 1)$.  Above, I chose the weights $w_i$ arbitrarily, but could I place constraints on them such that when they are combined with the $p_i$ that the sum remains 1?

Comment: You could say that $\sum w_i p_i=1$, but I don't see any other way to specify the requirement.